# Template Syntax Error in Django due to calling a link by url name after deploying to EC2 instance

Tags: django, url, deployment, amazon-ec2

I received the following error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /accounts/login/
Caught ImportError while rendering: No module named urls
```

due to this piece of code in a template:

```
<a href="{% url index %}">{% trans "Home" %}</a>
```

it happened after trying to deploy my django project to an amazon ec2 instance. I am confused as to why this would occur.

here is the full trace:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /accounts/login/
Caught ImportError while rendering: No module named urls
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://ec2-67-202-59-6.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8000/accounts/login/
Django Version: 1.3
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Caught ImportError while rendering: No module named urls
Exception Location: /opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py in import_module, line 35
Python Executable:  /opt/bitnami/python/bin/.python.bin
Python Version: 2.6.5
Python Path:    
['/opt/bitnami/projects/Project',
 '/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg',
 '/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3c1-py2.6-linux-i686.egg',
 '/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/haystack-0.16-py2.6.egg',
 '/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/argparse-1.2.1-py2.6.egg',
 '/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/python_ptrace-0.6.4-py2.6.egg',
 '/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/jsonfield-0.9-py2.6.egg',
 '/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_pagination-1.0.7-py2.6.egg',
 '/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_picklefield-0.2.0-py2.6.egg',
 '/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_registration-0.7-py2.6.egg',
 '/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_jsonfield-0.8.5-py2.6.egg',
 '/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/South-0.7.3-py2.6.egg',
 '/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_haystack-1.2.6-py2.6.egg',
 '/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages',
 '/opt/bitnami/projects/Project',
 '/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python26.zip',
 '/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.6',
 '/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2',
 '/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.6/lib-tk',
 '/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.6/lib-old',
 '/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload',
 '/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.6/site-packages',
 '/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PIL',
 '/opt/bitnami/projects/Project/cookbook']
Server time:    Tue, 4 Sep 2012 18:56:56 -0500
Template error

In template /opt/bitnami/projects/Project/templates/registration/base.html, error at line 56
Caught ImportError while rendering: No module named urls
46      </div><!--left_pane-container-->
47  </div><!--left_pane-->
48      
49  {% block container %}   
50  <div id="container">    
51      <div id="container_header">
52          <div id="header-content-container">
53                  <div id="container_header-items">
54                          {% block header_items %}
55                          {% endblock %}
56                          <a href="{% url index %}">{% trans "Home" %}</a> | 
57                          {% if user.is_authenticated %}
58                          {{ user.username }} 
59                          (<a href="{% url auth_logout %}">{% trans "Log out" %}</a> | 
60                          <a href="{% url auth_password_change %}">{% trans "Change password" %}</a>)
61                          <form action="/search/" method="get">
62                              <label for="id_q">Search:</label>
63                              <input id="id_q" name="q" type="text">
64                              <input type="submit" value="Submit">
65                          </form>
66                          {% else %}
```

here is the full traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://ec2-67-202-59-6.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8000/accounts/login/

Django Version: 1.3
Python Version: 2.6.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.comments',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'pagination',
 'cookbook',
 'registration',
 'ajax_validation',
 'south',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'accounts',
 'haystack',
 'json']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'pagination.middleware.PaginationMiddleware')


Template error:
In template /opt/bitnami/projects/Project/templates/registration/base.html, error at line 56
   Caught ImportError while rendering: No module named urls
   46 :     </div><!--left_pane-container-->


   47 : </div><!--left_pane-->


   48 :     


   49 : {% block container %}   


   50 : <div id="container">    


   51 :     <div id="container_header">


   52 :         <div id="header-content-container">


   53 :                 <div id="container_header-items">


   54 :                         {% block header_items %}


   55 :                         {% endblock %}


   56 :                         <a href=" {% url index %} ">{% trans "Home" %}</a> | 


   57 :                         {% if user.is_authenticated %}


   58 :                         {{ user.username }} 


   59 :                         (<a href="{% url auth_logout %}">{% trans "Log out" %}</a> | 


   60 :                         <a href="{% url auth_password_change %}">{% trans "Change password" %}</a>)


   61 :                         <form action="/search/" method="get">


   62 :                             <label for="id_q">Search:</label>


   63 :                             <input id="id_q" name="q" type="text">


   64 :                             <input type="submit" value="Submit">


   65 :                         </form>


   66 :                         {% else %}


Traceback:
File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  93.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  79.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py" in login
  69.                               context_instance=RequestContext(request, current_app=current_app))
File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py" in render_to_response
  20.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs)
File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  188.         return t.render(context_instance)
File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  123.             return self._render(context)
File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  117.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  744.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  73.             result = node.render(context)
File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  127.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  117.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  744.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  73.             result = node.render(context)
File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  64.             result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  744.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  73.             result = node.render(context)
File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  64.             result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  744.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  73.             result = node.render(context)
File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  437.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=context.current_app)
File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  391.             *args, **kwargs)))
File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  312.         possibilities = self.reverse_dict.getlist(lookup_view)
File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _get_reverse_dict
  229.             self._populate()
File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _populate
  208.                     for name in pattern.reverse_dict:
File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _get_reverse_dict
  229.             self._populate()
File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _populate
  197.         for pattern in reversed(self.url_patterns):
File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _get_url_patterns
  279.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _get_urlconf_module
  274.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)

Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError at /accounts/login/
Exception Value: Caught ImportError while rendering: No module named urls
```

Comment: My guess is - error  is elsewhere.. can you do a sitewide search for urls?

Comment: i have done so and a few occurrences have been found. what exactly should i be looking for? thanks karthikr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted my amazon instance and did everything over and it worked the second time around

thanks